# Views related content based same term names in different vocabulary

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to create a view for a taxonomy term and show a related content based on term name.

For example, i have term name Manchester United in vocabulary teams and i want to show all news nodes that have term Manchester United. The problem is that terms in news are in different vocabulary.

For now i create a View with Contextual filters Content: Has taxonomy term ID which get me ID for term Manchester United from vocabulary teams.

My questions is, how i can use this term name and show related nodes from news which have same term name but in different vocabulary and different ID.

EDIT: it's important to know that i'm getting first term by his ID in url.

Comment: Is this for Drupal 7 or 8?

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

**First option (doesn't work as expected though):**

You should be able to do that, by doing the following in your contextual filter:

1. Check the "Specify validation criteria" option.
2. Select "Taxonomy term" as "Validator".
3. Select "Term name" as "Filter value type".

I just tried this however and it returns only one result, which is not what you need.

**Alternative (this one was tested and works):**

You can create a View of Taxonomy Terms, and then use a "Taxonomy term: Name" contextual filter.
Afterwards, you can add a relationship to your tagged nodes, using the "Taxonomy term: Content with term" relationship.

That way, you can get all the content tagged with a specific term name, even if the term name belongs to different taxonomies.

Here is a sample View configuration:

[image]

and a sample result-set with "ManU" used as a contextual filter:

[image]

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but your Alternative works only if only my contextual filter is term name. In my case i have term id in url.

Comment: Okay, will think of an alternative. In the meantime, please update your OP, the information about having a Term ID in the URL is important.

Comment: I don't know what OP is. You want me to edit my question ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant :-) OP => Original Post

Comment: Hello, after so long. Now i'm trying to do this related posts with term name, but in view when i type "manchester united" it works, and when i open taxonomy page it doesn't. Its because name in url is not "manchester unite" and is "manchester-united". Any suggestons ?

Comment: Hi after so long. You should post this as a new question since it differs from this one. And try to update this one with information that would help others that land here with this same question.